# Putting XML data into Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, xml, google-sheets

I am trying to create a "database" of sorts in Google Sheets/Fusion Tables using XML files found online (giving information on bus routes and bus stops) so that I can eventually work with it in a Javascript program.  The bus stops are identified by a stop_id and the routes by a route tag.  I would like to connect these two in the database so that, given a stop_id I will know the route tag of the route the stop is on.  Each stop contains the stop_id and latitude/longitude information.  The routes contain lists of the stops (stop_id) in them.  To create this database, I would like a Google spreadsheet with the route tag as the column head and the list of stop IDs filling the corresponding cells below.  In total there are 30 routes.  The list of route tags is found on http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=chapel-hill and the route information for route A (for example) is found on http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeConfig&a=chapel-hill&r=A.  I have tried using the importxml("routesURL", "/body/route//stop[stopId]") command in Google sheets, but it returns a parse error or that "Imported content is empty" when I do so.  To reiterate my goal, I would like to know for a specific stop_id what the route tag is.  Any tips?  Is my strategy all wrong?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a typical xml, ie no real values inside the opening tag and closing tag. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml) is a typical xml file, from which `importxml` can extract `Tove`, `Jani`, `Reminder`, etc. Just Try:

```
=importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", "*")
```

But, in case of your first file, there's no values to extract.

I have searched and found [they also provide JSON format](https://gist.github.com/grantland/7cf4097dd9cdf0dfed14#gistcomment-2001605). Just replace `XML` to `JSON` in the URL like this:

```
http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicJSONFeed?command=routeConfig&a=chapel-hill&r=A
```

GS doesn't provide a built-in function for JSON, but you can [import JSON via GAS](https://www.google.com/search?q=gas+importjson).

Comment: I figured out that it actually works if you use =importxml(http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeConfig&a=chapel-hill&r=A, "//stop/@stopId") in the sheets cell.  This will grab the ID #s for each stop along the A route (and can be easily replicated for the other routes).  Thanks for the input, though!

Comment: Oops, good point! What I said applies to your first xml file only. You can surely extract `attribute`s for the second file with `importxml` like you did.